# Moving Python installation folder does not update ipython paths

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

I moved my Python 2.7 installation from C:\Python to D:\Python by simply moving the folder (I understand there are other ways to do this). When running **D:\Python\python.exe**, I can import system libraries and run things without any issues. However, I cannot run **D:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe.** I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python\python.exe" 
"D:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe" '
```

It seems that ipython is aware of its original installation directory C:\Python, and attempts to access it. Are there any startup options or enviornmental variables I can use to force ipython to use the new installation directory?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

The following process works completely fine. I first start Python via D:\Python\python.exe, and then run:

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```

Why would this be different from running D:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe?

Comment: Python installs values into the registry as well, so it may not be safe to move it just by moving the folder.

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue. The problem is that pip hardcodes the path to the Python interpreter for the executables in the Scripts folder (in this case IPython) at the time of the installation.

I don't think that is a way to control which Python interpreter pip should use for the executables. Currently, there are a couple of open issues on Github for pip that indicate that this is still an unsolved issue, e.g. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2845.

However, I found a workaround described in this post http://www.clemens-sielaff.com/create-a-portable-python-with-pip-on-windows/ that works for me. Basically, just open the exe file in a text editor and edit the path to the Python interpreter (you will find it almost at the end of the file as `#!<your path>`). I'm using `#!python` since I know that my Python interpreter of choice will be first in path.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue, since I am using a portable python app which comes via an installer.  As the other answers indicate, there is a hard coded path within the .exe which points to python in the original installer configuration.

The issue is that it's not just `pip.exe`, `ipython.exe`, or `jupyter.exe` that use this hard-coded path, but at least 20+ compiled exe scripts in the `.\python\Scripts` folder.  The solution, in my case, is **not to re-install** each module since that breaks the idea of the portable package. Plus, this will require additional internet resources which might not be available for the user.

The solution is to replace the path to the python.exe in the compiled scripts themselves.  Here is the solution which worked for me, from a previous [example](https://pythonhosted.org/pymyinstall/_modules/pymyinstall/win_installer/win_patch.html):

This is the code incase the link breaks:

```
"""
Patch the distribution to make it portable

"""
import os
import sys


def win_patch_paths(folder, python_path, path_to_python="", fLOG=print):
   """
    path are absolute when they are installed,
    see `Create a portable Python with Pip on Windows <http://www.clemens- 
    sielaff.com/create-a-portable-python-with-pip-on-windows/>`_

    :param      folder:          folder when to find the executable
    :param      python_path:     python path (string to replace)
    :param      path_to_python:  new python path (replace by)
    :param      fLOG:            logging function
    :return:                     list of tuple ('exe or py', 'modified file')

    The first three parameter can be environment variables.
    They will be replaced by their values.
    
   """
   if isinstance(python_path, list):
       operations = []
       for pyt in python_path:
          op = win_patch_paths(folder, pyt, path_to_python, fLOG)
          operations.extend(op)
       return operations
   else:
       if folder in os.environ:
          folder = os.environ[folder]
       if python_path in os.environ:
          python_path = os.environ[python_path]
          if python_path == "EMPTY_STRING":
             python_path = ""
       if path_to_python in os.environ:
          path_to_python = os.environ[path_to_python]

       files = os.listdir(folder)

       if len(python_path) > 0 and not python_path.endswith("\\"):
          python_path += "\\"
       if len(path_to_python) > 0 and not path_to_python.endswith("\\"):
          path_to_python += "\\"

       operations = []
       for prog in ["python.exe", "pythonw.exe"]:
          shebang = "#!" + python_path + prog
          bshebang = bytes(shebang, encoding="ascii")
          into = "#!" + os.path.normpath(path_to_python + prog)
          binto = bytes(into, encoding="ascii")

          fLOG("replace {0} by {1}".format(shebang, into))

          for file in files:
              full = os.path.join(folder, file)
              if os.path.isfile(full):
                  ext = os.path.splitext(full)[-1]

                  if ext in {".py", ""}:
                      with open(full, "r") as f:
                          content = f.read()
                    if shebang in content:
                        content = content.replace(shebang, into)
                        fLOG("update ", full)
                        operations.append(("update", full))
                        with open(full, "w") as f:
                            f.write(content)
              elif ext == ".exe":
                  with open(full, "rb") as f:
                      content = f.read()
                  if bshebang in content:
                      content = content.replace(bshebang, binto)
                      fLOG("update ", full)
                      operations.append(("update", full))
                      with open(full, "wb") as f:
                          f.write(content)
                  else:
                      pass

       return operations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    old = sys.argv[2]
    new = sys.argv[3]
    print("folder:",folder)
    print("old:",old)
    print("new:",new)

    op = win_patch_paths(folder=folder,python_path=old,path_to_python=new)
```

Call within python folder:

```
# Python paths are only the path, not including the python.exe as the path
.\python.exe Scripts <old python path> <new python path>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with respect to pip and had to upgrade my python installation to 2.7.6 and reinstall pip.