# Avoiding hard-coded Python install path on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ipython

I am making a custom Python distribution for Windows. The basic idea is that I collect the packages together on my PC and then generate an executable installer which I distribute, and when run it copies the distribution to an install location on the host PC.

It works fine for most libraries but I have found that for libraries with standalone executables, most notably IPython, the 'secondary' executables end up looking for the primary Python executable in the wrong place - specifically, on the path where the distribution was created, rather than where it was subsequently installed.

For example, suppose I create the distribution in C:\Dev\ and install to C:\Python\ (on a different PC). Then I get an error like:

```
C:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "C:\Dev\python.exe" "C:\Python\Scripts\ipython.exe"
```

On the other hand, executing Ipython via imports with `C:\Python\python.exe -m IPython` works fine.

Peering into the ipython.exe file I see that the original path "C:\Dev\python.exe" has been hard-coded inside it, presumably when it was installed by `pip`.

Is there a way to specify the (eventual) install path of python.exe instead the dev path when using pip? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Run `pip` after installing on the different PC?

Comment: http://portablepython.com  aims to address exactly this issue. It seems to have solved it for IPython among others.  Have you tried building up your custom distro based on a minimal Portable Python installation?

Comment: @RossRidge Not an option unfortunately, it needs to "just work"

Comment: @jez Yes, [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net) also seems to have managed it somehow. I may have to go source-diving.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371712/moving-python-installation-folder-does-not-update-ipython-paths ?